# Passing chosen multi select values to controller action

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to send the selected values of a chosen multi select list to an Action in my Controller. I've verified val() does show me an array of selected values like ["33","175"] when I print out to the console but the Action's argument is always null. I tried changing the argument type to object and verified it's not null but I can't parse the values. Any suggestions? Please and thanks!

Ajax call:

```
$(".chosen-select").on("change", function (event, params) {
    console.log($(".chosen-select").val());

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("BDOReferralSourcesTableHTML","ReferralNetwork")',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: { bdoIds: $(".chosen-select").val() },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.length > 0) {
                alert(response);
            }
            else {
                alert("response length zero");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult BDOReferralSourcesTableHTML(string[] bdoIds)
{
    return Content("<b>test</b>", "text/html");    
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have to set `traditional` property of ajax to `true`:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("BDOReferralSourcesTableHTML","ReferralNetwork")',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        traditional:true,
        data: { bdoIds: $(".chosen-select").val() },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.length > 0) {
                alert(response);
            }
            else {
                alert("response length zero");
            }
        }
    });
```

you can also set it globally so there is no need to specify it in every ajax call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    traditional:true
   });
```

### UPDATE:

Following is the reason why you need to set **`traditional:true`**:

> > **jQuery 1.4** adds support for nested param serialization in **`jQuery.param`**, using the approach popularized by PHP, and supported by Ruby on Rails. For instance, **`{foo: ["bar", "baz"]}`** will be serialized as **“foo[]=bar&foo[]=baz”**.
> >
> > In **jQuery 1.3**, **`{foo: ["bar", "baz"]}`** was serialized as **“foo=bar&foo=baz”**. However, there was no way to encode a single-element Array using this approach. If you need the old behavior, you can turn it back on by setting the traditional Ajax setting (globally via **`jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional`** or on a case-by-case basis via the traditional flag).

Details can be seen [**jQuery 1.4 Released – Full Release Notes**](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14) in **Ajax** section.

You can also see the explanation [**here. jQuery 1.4 breaks ASP.Net MVC actions with array parameters**](http://dovetailsoftware.com/clarify/kmiller/2010/02/24/jquery-1-4-breaks-asp-net-mvc-actions-with-array-parameters/)

Also see:  [**jQuery 1.4 breaks ASP.NET MVC parameter posting**](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-1-4-breaks-asp-net-mvc-parameter-posting)

Comment: Well that was easy. It worked!! Thank you and thanks for the links

Comment: You sir, are greater than the Great Leader of the North Career!

Comment: @banny in my post i have attached link which describes in detail